# Resolve "@typescript-eslint/no-invalid-this" issue for class fields without conflicting with "@typescript-eslint/no-this-alias"

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint, typescript-class

In below code:

```js
import { Vue, Component } from "vue-property-decorator";  


@Component({
  components: {}
})
export default class ProductViewingAndEditingPage extends Vue {

  private readonly componentsReferencesIDs: {
    productTitleInputField: string;
    productPriceInputControl: string;
  } = {
    productTitleInputField: "ProductTitle--InputField",
    productPriceInputControl: "ProductPrice--InputComponent"
  };

  private readonly productDataFormValidator: InputsGroupValidator = new InputsGroupValidator({
    controls: {
      [this.componentsReferencesIDs.productTitleInputField]:
          this.$refs[this.componentsReferencesIDs.productTitleInputField],
      [this.componentsReferencesIDs.productPriceInputControl]:
          this.$refs[this.componentsReferencesIDs.productPriceInputControl]
    }
  });
}
```

[@typescript/eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint) emits [@typescript-eslint/no-invalid-this](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-invalid-this.md) issue (because it's not ESLint's `no-invalid-this`, this rule understands the class fields.).

### Musings about conceptual solution

If I make `componentsReferencesIDs` to static class field, it's become impossible to retrieve the values from vue template.

Arrow functions could not be used here because here is class field. And also, if we alias `this`, we will face with [no-this-alias](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-this-alias.md) rule.

I understand that ESLint is not the sole source of truth. But I want the justification like "because 〈argument〉, this ESLint rule does not cover this case."

Comment: The level of configurability in modern linters has made them somewhat less effective. I rather miss the days of JS Lint. As it is, with everything configurable, yet with the supposed goal still being quality code, it seems like you have to decide for yourself. For example, I would flag your code for using `private`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is now working correctly in ESLint - just need to update your ESLint core and @typescript-eslint versions. [playground example](https://typescript-eslint.io/play/#ts=5.2.2&fileType=.tsx&code=PQKgpgzgNglgdgFwAQAEEE8AOkDGAnGTBAWklkWDgHtj4A3AQ1gBNiEALGCALiQCIwePFTx8QwAFAScUBhAhIACsOYBXHAgBqMMAHd4AcwCCcZgFFmMBIcUMDYJAG8JSJABI8YAGYQAhLwY4dABuKVccKgBbTCo4MEQIACVvQXicSABJABEFAF4nF1ckTBV1BAAVKygwDLhMVQQAMR0oZl4%2BZSo1DUqEauJiWvqmluY%2BABpC1xKusuUYdKGGgGFYhGEods7uhHn0gaWEVejY%2BIQ%2BQoBfUMKZnayGBAZGkUjNJhhmR5EkfOcipARRAbHgFAGuADaHC4ADoIic4glkl5UnB0hBshAYXcyr1qodmmBWgBdbhTcHQrEebwQKGcLHwmKIhBJFKeNGZHLY0o9Ko1OoNQkkybgpB02GM05ItlpTlYnEaPb84arYFUKCk8kAykw6k%2BcUMqJMs6slHs9GY7mzRUERYCo5rDbE8mXK6hV1AA&eslintrc=N4KABGBEBOCuA2BTAzpAXGYBfEWg&tsconfig=N4KABGBEDGD2C2AHAlgGwKYCcDyiAuysAdgM6QBcYoEEkJemy0eAcgK6qoDCAFutAGsylBm3TgwAXxCSgA&tokens=false)

---

Previous, outdated answer for posperity:

`@typescript-eslint/no-invalid-this` just hasn't had support for `this` in class properties added.

The extension rule was only added to the project relatively recently. At the time, the author worked on the feature they needed, which was support for `this` args.

As a community maintained project, we rely upon support from the community to help us add rules, add features and fix bugs.
If anyone wants to tackle this - please feel free to submit a PR - I believe that it should actually be a relatively simple fix.

Relevant issue on github: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/491

---

As an aside, this probably begs the question "why hasn't this been fixed in over a year!?"

Two reasons:

1. When you have the `noImplicitThis` compiler option turned on, TypeScript itself will throw a compiler error if you're using an invalid `this`.Because it's handled by TS directly, the vast majority of users don't feel the need to duplicate the error with a lint rule.
2. Not many users use `this` in class properties, meaning users aren't likely to run into this issue to begin with. Some users don't like that style of properties, but I believe most users don't actually know that it's valid to do this.

Putting these two together - few users use the lint rule, and fewer users still use `this` in class properties - so there hasn't been enough people to motivate the community to fix it.

Comment: I am still running into this issue.  But I noticed a pr had been approved to fix this.  Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: File an issue on GH. Stackoverflow comments are not a good place to get technical support as it's impossible to provide any context that allows me to actually help  you.